# How to solve Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 1

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

How to solve this issue. When I deleted data from this page this error on flutter web will be shown. Someone can help me.

[image]

Code on this page. When I click deviceListPage.dart:294:43 this error highlight on code line (_inventoryListByPage[i].deviceUID);
I hope someone can help me. I try to search for this error on google and stack overflow but I don't see an error same as me.

```
_deleteSelected() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < _inventoryListByPage.length; i++) {
      if (_inventoryListByPage[i].selected) {
        if (_inventoryListByPage[i].deviceUID != null) {
          if (_inventoryListByPage[i].deviceUID.length > 0) {
            await _clinicRemoveDevice(0, _inventoryListByPage[i].deviceUID);
            print(_inventoryListByPage[i].deviceUID);// Error at this line
          }
        }
      }
    }
    _getClinicInventory('');
  }
```

Comment: What does `_clinicRemoveDevice` do? The name suggests it removes the device, so logically it's no longer in the list after that

Comment: When I remove _clinicRemoveDevice. The device in the list can't remove when I select and delete it.

Comment: yeah I get that. But it's logical that after you remove it from a list it's no longer in the list, so you can't print it after. So it makes perfect sense that the print will cause an error.

Comment: So how to solve this issue. Can you give example in code?

Comment: remove the line, as the line is just print statement

Comment: yes what @Prabhakaran said, or put the print above the remove

Comment: When i remove print(_inventoryListByPage[i].deviceUID); . The error will be solved but data on the list will be repeated. For example, I add 2 data to the list. Device 1 and device 2. When I deleted device 1 it was successful and the error was not shown. But device 2 will be shown more than 1.

Comment: @JohnReaper that would be an error unrelated to the printing. There must be something wrong in the way your remove devices

Comment: Maybe. I don't have any idea to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The device is no longer in the list after you remove it so you can't access it in the list any more.

Either swap those statements, like this:

```
print(_inventoryListByPage[i].deviceUID);// Error at this line
await _clinicRemoveDevice(0, _inventoryListByPage[i].deviceUID);
```

Or use a local variable maybe like this

```
var uid = _inventoryListByPage[i].deviceUID;
await _clinicRemoveDevice(0, uid);
print(uid);
```

Or just leave the print out completely